# playing .mov files in android app

Tags: android, android-videoview

What are the ways to play .mov video formats in android application? Unfortunately, android does not support .mov video formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ExoPlayer component.
It's not an android component, but a Google third party component, so you could depend on them, will be stable.
I have used to play that kind of videos without problem

https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer

Hope it's helps